# Importing data with MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

I'm getting a strange error (EXC_BAD_ACCESS by CFStringGetLength within NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord)MR_executeFetchRequest:inContext:) I can't make sense of when attempting to import data from a JSON file...

```
NSManagedObjectContext *opContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];

NSString *jsonPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DefaultData"
                                                         ofType:@"json"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath];

NSError *parseError;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&parseError];

NSArray *dataTypes = [json objectForKey:@"dataTypes"];

[MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    for (NSDictionary *obj in dataTypes) {
        [BTDataType MR_importFromObject:obj inContext:localContext];
    }
}];

NSError *saveError;
[opContext save:&saveError];
```

The entity is very simple, just two properties: importKey (int16) and name (String)...

The JSON is like...

```
{
    "dataTypes":[
         {
             "importKey":1000,
             "name":"DataType A"
         },
         {
             "importKey":1001,
             "name":"DataType B"
         },
         {
             "importKey":1002,
             "name":"DataType C"
         },
         {
             "importKey":1003,
             "name":"DataType D"
         }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. I was able to solve it by selecting my entity in Xcode then adding a userInfo key/value. So for you, you would want to add a key/value of `'relatedByAttribute':'importKey'`.

See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18370739/442695