# Magical Record import issue with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, magicalrecord

I am having an issue with Magical Record. I have an array of items that are `ProviderSearchResult` objects that I need to import. When I import them I keep getting an **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** for

```
#24 0x00008770 in __67+[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord) MR_executeFetchRequest:inContext:]_block_invoke at
MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObject/NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m:33
```

I have searched high and low on how to get this resolved but nothing is working. My code is

```
ApiClient *client = [ApiClient sharedInstance];

NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[searchString] forKeys:@[@"companyName"]];
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dataDictionary options:0 error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *token = [[[UserManager sharedInstance] getAuthenticationObject] authenticationToken];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"json", token, jsonString ]
                                                                   forKeys:@[@"callType", @"token", @"data"]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
[client getPath:@"GetClientInterfaces/" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    NSLog(@"Operation: %@", operation);
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
    NSLog(@"Type: %@", [[responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"details.items"] class]);
    NSLog(@"First: %@", [[responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"details.items"] firstObject]);
    NSArray *providerResults = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"details.items"];
    NSLog(@"Results: %@", providerResults);
    __block NSArray *array;
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        array = [ProviderSearchResults MR_importFromArray:providerResults inContext:localContext];
    }];
    NSLog(@"Array: %@", array);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    NSLog(@"Operation: %@", operation);
    NSLog(@"Shit: %@", error);
}];
```

Can anyone see anything wrong that would cause this not to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long conversation with the developers it came down to a primary key not being assigned to the entity.

I had to select the entity in Xcode then in the userInfo section I added a key/value of `'relatedByAttribute':'clientMasterId'`.

`clientMasterId` will now be my primaryKey according to MR